# unable to configure cntlm on ubuntu for NTLM authentication

Tags: ubuntu, proxy

I am trying to setup cntlm on ubuntu13 for NTLM authentication.  I used apt-get install to setup ctlm.  My cntlm.conf file in the etc directory is copied below - the username/domain and password are correct (I have tested them with a different application).  However, when I try to start cntlm via /etc/init.d/ntlm start (or restart), it always fails with the error message copied at the end.  Any suggestions to fix or troubleshoot this will be greatly appreciated.

**cntlm.conf**

```
# Cntlm Authentication Proxy Configuration

Username        account
Domain          xxxxxx.com
Password        password
# NOTE: Use plaintext password only at your own risk
# Use hashes instead. You can use a "cntlm -M" and "cntlm -H"
# command sequence to get the right config for your environment.
# See cntlm man page
# Example secure config shown below.
# PassLM          1AD35398BE6565DDB5C4EF70C0593492
# PassNT          77B9081511704EE852F94227CF48A793
### Only for user 'testuser', domain 'corp-uk'
# PassNTLMv2      D5826E9C665C37C80B53397D5C07BBCB

# Workstation   netbios_hostname

###Proxy                10.0.0.41:8080
###Proxy                10.0.0.42:8080

NoProxy         localhost, 127.0.0.*, 10.*, 192.168.*, 0.0.*

Listen          3128

#SOCKS5Proxy    8010
#SOCKS5User     dave:password

#Auth           LM
#Flags          0x06820000

#Gateway        yes

#Allow          127.0.0.1
#Deny           0/0

#ISAScannerSize     1024
#ISAScannerAgent    Wget/
#ISAScannerAgent    APT-HTTP/
#ISAScannerAgent    Yum/

#Header         User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows 98)
#Tunnel         11443:remote.com:443
```

**Error Message:**

```
Stopping CNTLM Authentication Proxy: cntlm.
Starting CNTLM Authentication Proxy: failed!
```

**Update**:
When I ran the following:

```
cntlm -v -c cntlm.conf
```

the error message mentioned the following:

**Error**

```
cntlm: Parent proxy address missing.
Exitting with error. Check daemon logs or run with -v.
```

**Another Update:**

I removed the uncommented hashtags from the proxy flags and cntlm appears to be running.  I will update this post if I come across any issues.

**Update**
cntlm appears to be running on port 3128.  I pointed IE to use the proxy on the correct IP address and port number - however, the connection times out.  Any suggestions on troubleshooting this wil be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are several different issues with your configuration files:

- first, you forgot to specify parent proxy which is used to pass your NTLM credentials to, you fixed this already (uncommented "Proxy" directive as far as I can understand).
- now add your IP address to "Allow" directive, I suggest to add both 127.0.0.1 for localhost and your external IP address assigned to Ethernet interface, for example, if your subnet is 192.168.1.0/24, and you have IP address for your workstation 192.168.1.10 then directive should look

```
Allow 127.0.0.1
Allow 192.168.1.10
```

Simple restart after that will do the trick. Then you can use either 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.1.10 as proxy server in IE or any other browser to make it work using cntlm.

Comment: thank you for sharing.  This is what I have done so far - I added the local IP address for the server as well as my computer's address in the Allow section of cntlm.conf.  I tried NTLM auth after cntlm restart but it did not work.  I am trying this with squid.  Perhaps my understanding of this setup is faulty - should I try another proxy or a specific setting in squid to allow this connection to properly establish?

Comment: If you're using squid as parent you just create chain of proxies where CNTLM is your first (closer to you) proxy and squid is the next in chain. You need to make sure squid is able to process such requests. By "able to process" I mean it should accept requests at all and be able to recognize NTLM part of HTTP auth request. You need to take a look at squid logs in order to determine how this activity processed on it. Please also pay attention to any firewalls between cntlm and squid and the fact that cntlm may explicitly request NTLM response and fail if squid knows nothing about NTLM.